# Magento 2 - How to delete store view

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, store-view, stores

I need to delete a store view, but there is no way.

How does it work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend you need to go `STORES -> Settings > All stores`, the store view, and press on the "Delete Store View" link at the top:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**I would not recommend deleting a storeview from the backend.** There is a good chance your request will time out and give you all sorts of trouble.

If you still want to do it **make backups**!

An alternative way would be to dump the current configuration into `app/etc/config.php` (`app:config:dump`) and edit the confg.php stores section to your needs. Then do a `setup:upgrade`. This will make sure the deleted stores from the `config.php` will be deleted from the database as well.

The system will ask if you actually want to delete the stores. This way you have full control.

Answer (score 0):

You should go storeview detail page by click on storeview link.

For Delete Storeview follow below steps.
Go Admin > Stores > All stores.

Select storeview which you want to remove. press button "Delete Store View". It would take some time.

After it execute below commands.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset;
php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
php bin/magento cache:clean;
```

After Update permission of var cache pub/static folder.

Comment: Never use chmod 777

Comment: yes, for security we could not use. generally i used to for ubuntu local server.